# Calling servlet doPost method in the javascript

Tags: javascript, servlets

I want to call Servlet doPost() method  by using the javascript code but iam getting  http 405(HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL) exception.

Here is my javascript code:

```
  url="RedirectServlet?&FD="+FD+"&TD="+TD+"&actionid="+status+"&usercode="+usercode+"&action=reports"+"";
```

RedirectServlet.java:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
        {
 if(action.equals("reports")){
        System.out.println("inside reports");

        //Getting values from Reports_arb.jsp
        String Fromdate=request.getParameter("FD");
        String Todate=request.getParameter("TD");
        String status=request.getParameter("actionid");
        String usercode=request.getParameter("usercode");

        //placing given values in a session 

        request.setAttribute("FD", Fromdate);
        request.setAttribute("TD", Todate);
        request.setAttribute("actionid", status);
        request.setAttribute("usercode", usercode);


        //Redirecting to showReport_arb.jsp
        //response.sendRedirect("showReport_arb.jsp");

        request.getRequestDispatcher("showReport_arb.jsp").include(request, response);

    }  
  }
```

Comment: It seems you are making a GET request, which the server doesn't accept. It seems to accept POST only, hence its name

Comment: by default, your request is GET and servlet does not accept GET. I think you should change to POST in the request header.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your immediate reply.How do we make a post request to servlet from javascript

Comment: See, [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/1037210) and you'll never have to scratch your head from soon onwards, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

By seeing you `URL`, you are `sending` the `data along with the URL`. which as `servlet` `get` request.

So `URL` is trying access `doGet`, but where there is no implemention of `doGet` in `servlet` causing problem.

**EDIT**

use this to make access of your servlet `doPost`

```
<form ...   method="post">...</form>
```

Comment: i want to hide the url data in the redirect jsp(above showreports_arb.jsp) thats why i used doPost() method in my servlet